# Upgrade 14.04.5 LTS to 16 LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, 16.04, package-management, do-release-upgrade

When trying to `do-release-upgrade` I get an error saying: `An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade`

When I checked the log in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` it says I have broken packages...

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
Broken dpkg:amd64 Breaks on php5-fpm [ amd64 ] < 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.20 > ( php ) (< 5.6.4+dfsg-3~)
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 > ( perl ) (< 5.22.1~)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ amd64 ] < 204-5ubuntu20.19 > ( admin )
Broken libkrb5support0:amd64 Breaks on libkdb5-7 [ amd64 ] < 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 > ( libs ) (< 1.13~alpha1-1)
Broken libasprintf0v5:amd64 Breaks on libasprintf0c2 [ amd64 ] < 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on libcgi-pm-perl [ amd64 ] < none -> 4.26-1 > ( perl )
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on perl [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (< 5.19)
Broken libcwidget3v5:amd64 Conflicts on libcwidget3 [ amd64 ] < 0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libgdal1i:amd64 Breaks on libgdal1h [ amd64 ] < 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp4)
Broken libxapian22v5:amd64 Conflicts on libxapian22 [ amd64 ] < 1.2.16-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libgeos-c1v5:amd64 Breaks on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.4.2-8~)
Broken aptitude:amd64 Depends on libcwidget3v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.5.17-4ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:amd64 Depends on libgdal1h [ amd64 ] < 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.0)
Broken postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:amd64 Depends on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.2)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4)
Broken libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsigc++-2.0-0c2a [ amd64 ] < 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-chardet-whl [ amd64 ] < 2.2.1-2~ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 2.3.0-2)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-colorama-whl [ amd64 ] < 0.2.5-0.1ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 0.3.6-1)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-distlib-whl [ amd64 ] < 0.1.8-1ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 0.2.2-1)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-html5lib-whl [ amd64 ] < 0.999-3~ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 0.999-4)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-requests-whl [ amd64 ] < 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.3 > ( python ) (< 2.9.1-3)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-setuptools-whl [ amd64 ] < 3.3-1ubuntu2 > ( python ) (< 20.1.1-1)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-six-whl [ amd64 ] < 1.5.2-1ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 1.10.0-3)
Broken python-pip-whl:amd64 Breaks on python-urllib3-whl [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-1ubuntu4 > ( python ) (< 1.13.1-2)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on libcgi-pm-perl [ amd64 ] < none -> 4.26-1 > ( perl )
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on perl [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (< 5.19)
Broken libgdal1i:amd64 Breaks on libgdal1h [ amd64 ] < 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp4)
Broken libgeos-c1v5:amd64 Breaks on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.4.2-8~)
Broken postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:amd64 Depends on libgdal1h [ amd64 ] < 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.0)
Broken postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:amd64 Depends on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.2)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on libcgi-pm-perl [ amd64 ] < none -> 4.26-1 > ( perl )
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on perl [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (< 5.19)
Broken libgdal1i:amd64 Breaks on libgdal1h [ amd64 ] < 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp4)
Broken libgeos-c1v5:amd64 Breaks on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.4.2-8~)
Broken postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:amd64 Depends on libgdal1h [ amd64 ] < 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.0)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4)
Broken python3.4-minimal:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4)
Broken libspatialite5:amd64 Depends on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.2)
Broken liblwgeom-2.1.2:amd64 Depends on libgeos-c1 [ amd64 ] < 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.2)
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on libcgi-pm-perl [ amd64 ] < none -> 4.26-1 > ( perl )
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on perl [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (< 5.19)
Broken python3.4:amd64 Depends on python3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4)
```

How do I go about fixing these issues?

Comment: Do not attempt a Release Upgrade without fully updating your current system and preferably also disable any third-party PPAs.

Comment: it's already fully updated and ran dist-upgrade as well, nothing left to upgrade.

Comment: @James I fully recommend a clean install; an upgrade often can break older packages.

Comment: @Patrick that's not an option.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install -f` ? If that doesn't work try this thread: [947124](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug with ubuntu that's over 4 years old that they won't fix. When you have the postgis extension on a postgresql database

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/996916

Comment: I purged postgis then do-release-upgrade worked. Thanks a lot!